# Xively trigger doesn't work

Tags: python, triggers, xively

This is very weird for me, when trying to configure a criteria based trigger (i.e greater than 3) the HTTP POST didn't work.
It worked fine on "freezes" trigger and the trigger test button as well.

The sensor is sending a value & i can see the value in the feed and the data stream.

Any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried sending a test trigger and confirm that it is received? Can you confirm the POST is not being received by your endpoint? You can try using http://requestb.in/ as the URL in the trigger to help debug your requests.

The other thing to check is that the value you are sending is in fact parseable to an integer or float.

Comment: Can you post more info about your trigger. What criteria you are using? And what data you are sending?

Comment: followed https://xively.com/dev/tutorials/pi/ and the trigger was set to be greater than 50